# shape keys not working

Tags: shape-keys

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on how to animate moths. I'm using shape keys and when I put a key frame in the shape keys and add some noise the moth does not move even though the shape key value is clearly changing.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :) [images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/200104/edit) and [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) may make your question more easily understood. Please consider an [edit] to your Q to add more information that other users would find helpful in answering your Q. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ian Hubert Lazy Tutorials if I'm not mistaken.

You need to add the shape key, put the value to 1 *and modify the wing position*. Keyframe/noise after that.

You don't see the wings moving because you didn't modify the wing position with the shape key at 1.0, by the looks of it.

Comment: that is what i did but it still doesn't work

Comment: Just to re-trace your steps. For the Wing object you're - 

-creating a shape key (Key 1)
-set Key 1 value to 1
-go into edit mode and rotate the wing (every selected vertex) to get a second wing position
-go out of edit mode and do the keying